# What happens if I play a mobile game I was made to swear not to play on the Quran?

Tags: quran, oaths

Today an incident happened. I am so addicted to a game on my mobile, my father saw this and he took the Quran and made me to promise that I won't play the game from now onwards.

But I am so addicted to this game. What happens if I play it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it's not allowed to make a promise by putting one's hand on the Quran. It's an act of innovation in Islam, and not proved from any verse of Quran or hadith.

Secondly, if you break a promise, then here in the Quran it explains what you have to do:

> Allah does not take you to task for your inadvertent oaths, but He
>   will take you to task for oaths you make intentionally. The expiation
>   in that case is to feed ten poor people with the average amount you
>   feed your family, or clothe them, or free a slave. Anyone without the
>   means to do so should fast three days. That is the expiation for
>   breaking oaths when you have sworn them. Keep your oaths. In this way
>   Allah makes His Signs clear to you, so that hopefully you will be
>   thankful. (Surat al-Ma'ida, 89)